# How to get OTT/TTF font unicode range it supports?

Tags: aspose, google-fonts, aspose.words, google-noto

I am using `Google noto fonts` with `Aspose` to export Word to PDF. I have custom configurations defined for fonts with a Unicode range. How can I get Unicode range for the selected Google Noto font to include new font?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the list of supported languages on the font's page. For example here:
https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Arabic/glyphs

Then you can find Unicode range for languages here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script

Alternatively, you can use some font inspecting tool, like `FontForge` to check what glyphs are available in the font.